# Mongo vs writing a plain file

Tags: mongodb, docker, pymongo

I am writing an entire Pandas DataFrame as bytestream into a flat file and into a Mongo Database, e.g here

```
import logging
from io import BytesIO

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pymongo import MongoClient
from uuid import uuid4

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

MONGODB_SETTINGS = {"Local": {'host': 'host.docker.internal',
                              'port': 27017}}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("Start")
    frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=list("ABCDE"), data=np.random.randn(300_000, 5))
    logger.info("Constructed Frame (object)")

    name = str(uuid4())
    bytestream = frame.to_parquet()
    post = {"frame": bytestream, "name": name}
    logger.info("Dictionary constructed")

    with open('data/tmp/output', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(bytestream)

    logger.info("Bytestrem written to disk")

    for key, settings in MONGODB_SETTINGS.items():
        logger.info(50 * "-")
        logger.info(key)

        with MongoClient(**settings) as client:
            db = client.capture
            collection = db.frame
            logger.info("Start writinng into Database")
            collection.insert_one(post)
            logger.info("Object written to Database")

            # read the frame back from database
            x = collection.find_one({"name": name})
            with BytesIO(x["frame"]) as buffer:
                frame_out = pd.read_parquet(buffer)

            logger.info("Object read from Database")
            pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(frame, frame_out)
            logger.info(50 * "-")
```

It takes like 0.1s to write the file where as it takes 3s to write into the Mongo Database. The database is hosted on my local computer and runs within the standard Mongo image. Am I missing something. Is that loss of speed normal?

Answer (score 0):

With code as ineffecient as that, yes.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to improve the code